# How to make sqlDependency work with left join?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, signalr, sqldependency

Iam using Sqldependency to monitor my table changes in the database the problem is Sqldependency not work when query contains left join to another table.
After research I find that on of the sqldependency limitation its not work with left join.
how I can handle this issue ?

```
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CustomerConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            //NOTE: [dbo].[CutomerInfo] WITH [dbo] IS MANDATORY WHILE USING SQL DEPENDENCY
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [CusId],[CusName], LocationName FROM [dbo].[CutomerInfo]  
                                                         left join [dbo].[CustomerLocations] on  [dbo].[CustomerLocations].[CustomerId] =[dbo].[CutomerInfo].CusId
                                                         WHERE [Status] <> 0", connection))
            {
                // Make sure the command object does not already have
                // a notification object associated with it.
                command.Notification = null;

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                //COMMAND EXECUTION IS MANDATORY
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                var listCus = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            CusId = (int)x["CusId"],
                            CusName = (string)x["CusName"],
                            LocationName = (x["LocationName"]==DBNull.Value)?"":(string)x["LocationName"]
                        }).ToList();

                return Json(new { listCus = listCus }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
        }
    }


  private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something
       
    }
```

I know that join and inner join work with Sql dependency but I need left join

Comment: You can set up a separate dependency to the table you're joining and monitor the original query without the join; if rows in either table changed, re-run the query. Do note that `SqlDependency` is rather flaky and hard to use; you may have to use periodic polling anyway.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, did you mean create dependency for the two tables and any table data changed  I execute another query that contains left join but not associated with SQL dependency  just to get data and related data?

Comment: Yes. Your dependency can't contain a `LEFT JOIN`, so it should just leave out the `LocationName`. If you actually don't expect the `CusName` to change or you're not interested in changes on that, you only need to monitor the `CustomerLocations` table. In this case you will also get notifications for any location changes for customers that have a `Status` of `0` (at least I assume that's a column in the (misspelled) `CutomerInfo` table -- always prefix every column when joining!) so you should be prepared for your `LEFT JOIN` query to not actually see any changes.